# How do I convert data in this format to a table?

Tags: excel, delimited

I have data that is in a big text file that looks like this:

`{"id": 111, "role": "manager", "name": "John doe"}` with every "row" of info separated by swirly brackets. How do I get this to be a table in excel? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is all in one cell?

Comment: It's just one big text file, it's not even in excel. So yes ultimately in one cell. What would be rows are delimited by the {}

Comment: It looks like you have row and column info. What symbol is each of the rows separated by? Can you give a larger sample of the data?

Comment: Never mind. I just re-read the question.

Comment: When you copy and paste it into excel is it all in one row or multiple rows within one column?

Comment: For Excel versions that support Power Query, there are few ways to read JSON http://superuser.com/questions/977249/loading-a-json-file-into-power-query/977376#977376

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import Json in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237345/import-json-in-excel)

Comment: It is called JSON file, just look on Google how to open it and manage data with Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have what is called a JSON object in the text file and it needs to be converted to a CSV file to be opened in Excel. I would use this tool to convert it to CSV and from there you can start modifying data in Excel. Hope it helps :)

https://json-csv.com/

EDIT: There is a PayPal after 1mb file size so use https://konklone.io/json/ to convert larger files for free.

Comment: If this answer works out, please set it as the correct answer :)

Comment: Hi, not seeing a button to do that although it worked perfectly.

Comment: Click the check to the left of my answer and press the up arrow :)

Comment: Also I used a different converter as the one you linked had a paywall after 1mb file size - I used https://konklone.io/json/

Comment: You're the best! I will post an edit based on your comment.

Comment: I can't believe nobody mentioned Notepad and a bit of old skool Find and Replace. Don't even have to save as a CSV file if you put in your own TABs just copy and paste into Excel.  Whatever they're charging, I'll do it for half the price ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:

1>> copy the information into cell `A1`. (if it puts it into multiple rows then skip to step 8.)

[image]

2>> on the top there are a few tabs. go to the one that says `Data`. Then go to `Text to Columns`

[image]

3>> then click on the button that says `Delimited` and then click next.

[image]

4>> then check the box that says `Other` and in the text box put a `{` and hit finish

[image]

5>> next, highlight and copy all of the cells.

[image]

6>> click on cell `A2`. Right click and select `Transpose`.

[image]

7>> now clear the top row.

[image]

8>> next, select column `A` and repeat the steps 2 and 3. Go to `Data > Text to Columns > Delimited > Next`.

[image]
[image]

9>> check the box named `Comma`, change the input for `other` to `:`, and click next.

[image]

10>> for each of the columns with the column names, select the `Do not import column (skip)` option

[image]
[image]

11>> hit `Ctrl+F` and select the `Replace` tab.

[image]

12>> in the `Find what:` input, put `"` and leave the `Replace with:` input blank. Click `Replace All` and okay.

[image]

13>> repeat step 12 replacing the `Find what:` input with `"}`.

[image]

14>> next, add the column headers in the first row.

[image]

15>> with any of the data cells selected, hit `Ctrl+L` and click `OK`.

[image]

16>> now all of your data is in a nice organized table.

[image]